# setuptools doesn't discover packages

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py

I installed setuptool and configured setup.py to manage my packages, but it doesn't work. here is the aborescence of my packages.

```
projectFolder
+
|
+--api
|   +
|   |
|   +--app.py
|   |
|   +
+--models
|  +
|  |
|  +--base_models.py
|  |
|  +--engine
|  |
+--tests
|  +
|   |
|   +--tests_models
|     +
|     |
|     +--test_base.py
|
|
+--setup.py
```

here my setup.py file

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(name="vidconvertor",
      version='0.0.1',
      packages= ['models', 'tests',  'api'],
)
```

I imported test_base in test_base.py, but I got this error  `File "/home/rodolphe/alx_vid_project/mp4_to_mp3/tests/test_models/./test_model.py", line 3, in <module> from models.base_model import BaseModel ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models.base_model'`

this my test_model.py content

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from models.base_model import BaseModel

print("enfin")
```

base_models.py content

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

class BaseModel:
    pass
```

to install setup.py i used   `python setup.py install`
any suggestion?

Comment: Check this tutorial: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/

Comment: Python modules do not need the shebang `#!/usr/bin/python3`. Only Python scripts do, but even then I recommend a shebang like this `!#/usr/bin/env python`.

Comment: You are missing the `__init__.py` files in each importable package and sub-package.

Comment: and error says "models.base_model.py" but the graph says "models.base_model**s**.py"

Comment: I removed this shebang ` #!/usr/bin/python3` as you suggested and in a first time use the python command to execute the file, it worked perfectly, in a second time I used  this  ` #!/usr/bin/env python `  iand it worked too... so the problem came from this shebang ` #!/usr/bin/python3 `